# Syntax error in SQL query with attributes containing sub queries

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I am writing SQL query where I need three columns. One of those is COUNT which is a result of multiple sub queries. I am getting an error "SQL command not properly ended" at FROM.. line. I suppose it's a syntax error and has something to do with the COUNT part above. Could I get some help regarding what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT STUDENTS.NAME AS NAME,
      ADDRESS.CITY AS CITY,
      COUNT(*) AS MY_COUNT FROM (SELECT MYSTATE FROM SOME_TABLE
                                  WHERE SOME_ATTRIBUTE IN 
                                                   (SELECT SUBQUERY_2 = 
                                                                     (SUBQUERY_3))) 
FROM MYSCHEMA.ADDRESS ADDRESS --Error: SQL command not properly ended
  INNER JOIN SCHEMA.STUDENTS STUDENTS
  ON ADDRESS.ID=STUDENTS.ID

GROUP BY STUDENTS.NAME, STUDENTS.CITY
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Eh, you have two `FROM`s: `FROM (SELECT MYSTATE ...` and `FROM MYSCHEMA.ADDRESS ...`. There has to be only one `FROM` clause. That's why you get the error at the second `FROM` clause.

Comment: In your query, there is two From  That's why you get an error at second From clause.

Comment: Thanks, @KavalPatel, @sticky bit. What's the correct way to collect `MY_COUNT` when it has to be a result of a sub query?

Comment: @zimmer, please check I am posting the answer and let me know you will get your answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Try this solution:

```
SELECT STUDENTS.NAME AS NAME,ADDRESS.CITY AS CITY,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_ATTRIBUTE IN (SELECT SUBQUERY_2 = (SUBQUERY_3))) AS MY_COUNT 
FROM MYSCHEMA.ADDRESS ADDRESS 
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.STUDENTS STUDENTS  ON ADDRESS.ID=STUDENTS.ID
GROUP BY STUDENTS.NAME, STUDENTS.CITY
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your first FROM is somehow related to the table/query you want to do your count on.  If that is so, this is the wrong form to do that.  You need to turn this into a scalar subquery :

```
SELECT STUDENTS.NAME AS NAME,
      ADDRESS.CITY AS CITY,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) WHERE ...) AS MY_COUNT  
FROM MYSCHEMA.ADDRESS ADDRESS 
...
```

What needs to go inside the inner FROM/WHERE is not guessable from what you gave us.  That's because "One of those is COUNT which is a result of multiple sub queries" is just hopelessly insufficient as an explanation of *WHAT* you are trying to achieve (count) *PRECISELY*.  So if you want help on that, explain in detail *HOW* "COUNT is a result of multiple subqueries".